# Temerse vs Tener miedo de

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Quiero decir "I'm afraid I will indulge in playing the game." y lo traduje como a continuación:

1.1. Tengo miedo de que vaya a dejarme llevar en este juego.

1.2. Tengo miedo de que vaya a ser indulgente en este juego.

1.3. Tengo miedo de que vaya a darme gusto    en este juego.

1.4. Tengo miedo de que vaya a gustarme mucho en este juego.

Dice que las de arriba **no son correctos**, ¿por qué?

2.1. Tengo miedo de dejarme llevar en el juego.

2.2. Tengo miedo de  ser indulgente en este juego

2.3. Tengo miedo de darme un gusto en este juego

2.4. Tengo miedo de que que me va a gustar mucho este juego.

2.5. Me Temo dejarme llevar en el juego.

2.6.  Me Temo ser indulgente en este juego

2.7. Me Temo darme un gusto en este juego

Dice que las de arriba **tampoco son correctos**, ¿por qué?

Y dice que las siguientes **son correctas**, ¿por qué?:

3.1. Temo dejarme llevar en el juego. ¿Por qué?

3.2. Temo ser indulgente en este juego

3.3. Temo darme un gusto en este juego.

3.4. Temo que me va a gustar mucho este juego.

**qué diferencias hay entre** *"temer/temerse" y "tener miedo de"?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las oraciones 1.1, 1.2 y 1.4 son correctas, pero estilísticamente podrían ser mejores. La 1.2 expresa que vas a hacer benevolente y que vas a perdonar los errores del  resto de jugadores (ver [indulgente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LRjaY36)). La 1.3:

> Tengo miedo de que vaya a darme gusto en este juego.

...es incorrecta porque el sujeto de la subordinada es (o debería ser) "este juego". Un sujeto jamás puede estar introducido por "en", por lo que el interlocutor debe revaluar la oración suponiendo que alguien no mencionado te va a dar gusto en un juego. La frase correcta sería:

> Tengo miedo de que vaya a darme gusto este juego.

Pero igual que las otras, tampoco suena genial.

De 2.1 a 2.3 has utilizado formas no personales. No son gramaticalmente incorrectas, pero no significan lo mismo que la oración en inglés. Estas últimas tres expresan que literalmente no te atreves a dejarte llevar porque te da miedo, no que tengas el presentimiento de que va a ser así. El equivalente inglés podría ser:

> I'm afraid of indulging in playing this game.

2.4 es una frase extraña. No creo que sea gramaticalmente incorrecta, pero no sé si terminaría de entender qué quiere decir si la oyera.

Con 2.5 a 2.7 has usado probablemente la estructura más adecuada para traducir *I'm afraid I will*: "me temo". Sin embargo, este debería ir seguido del indicativo o subjuntivo. He aquí por qué:

> Cuando se construye con indicativo, temer expresa 'sospecha o recelo', contenidos que suelen asociarse con las creencias o las percepciones. Es de resaltar que los complementos más frecuentes en estos casos sean las oraciones formadas con futuros o con perífrasis verbales de sentido prospectivo:
>
> *Temo que hallaré la muerte fría.*
>
> (...) El empleo del indicativo asciende notablemente con el verbo pronominal *temerse*, en cuyo complemento se registran los dos modos. Se muestra el indicativo en [este ejemplo]:
>
> *Me temo que tendré que salir de casa*
>
> (...) y el subjuntivo en [este otro]:
>
> *Pues yo me temía que no viniera*
>
> [Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/buscar.cgi)

Como se puede observar *temo* también es válido, pero si no va seguido de un verbo conjugado puede ser ambiguo: "Temo perder" puede ser tanto *I'm afraid I will lose* como *I'm afraid of losing*. En este caso la ambigüedad no es tan acentuada en 3.1 (por eso es correcta). 3.2 no es una buena traducción por las mismas razones expuestas en 1.2. La 3.3 es correcta, pero no suena muy bien. La mejor traducción de lejos es 3.4:

> Temo que me va a gustar mucho este juego.

Igualmente correcta sería la versión con *Me temo*:

> Me temo que me va a gustar mucho este juego.

---

En conclusión, "tengo miedo" no es una buena traducción para *I'm afraid* porque la expresión española es mucho más negativa que la inglesa y se relaciona más con la idea de *to be scared*. "Temo" y "me temo" son buenas traducciones, sobre todo usadas con frases  personales. Se suele usar el indicativo para referirse al presente o futuro: "temo que caeré en la tentación", "me temo que no saldrá bien", "me temo que ya es demasiado tarde"; y el subjuntivo para referirse el pasado: "temía que se te olvidara", "me temía que no fueras a venir".

Con frases impersonales, ya no está tan claro si se habla de predicciones o de un significado más literal de la palabra "temer": "Temo volar en avión" se refiere claramente a una fobia, pero "me temo que tendré que volar en avión" no. En estos casos, el contexto debería ser suficiente para aclararlo.

Comment: Gracias. Creo que he preguntado poco claro. Quise saber como se dice en español "I am afraid I will spend much in playing the game time more than good. It's not good." Tal vez los oraciones que puse no son correctas ....  y en inglés, "indulge" significa que "[I or T] to ​allow yourself or another ​person to have something ​enjoyable, ​especially more than is good for you:The ​soccer ​fans indulged ​their ​patriotism, ​waving​flags and ​singing ​songs.I ​love ​champagne but I don't often indulge my​self. [T] to give someone anything they ​want and not to ​mind if they ​behave ​badly: "

Comment: "Indulge" is one of those difficult to translate words. There's no such word as *indulgir* in Spanish, so all you can do is look for synonyms that don't capture the whole meaning of "indulge", or try to paraphrase the original sentence. An appropriate translation could be: "Me temo que voy a dedicarle a este juego más tiempo del que debería" or "Me temo que voy a dedicarle a este juego más tiempo del que me puedo permitir". The second one is maybe a little bit more emphatic.

Comment: Ya veo. Gracias. Entonces, "tener miedo de" es más grave que  "temerse"?

Comment: Más que una expresión grave, "tener miedo" está relacionado con el significado literal de "miedo", no con prever algo que generalmente es negativo (me temo que no podré ir) o con lamentar algo (temo informarle que...).

Answer (score 1):

Here my comments:

1.1 Tengo miedo de que vaya a dejarme llevar **por** este juego.

1.2 is correct

1.3 we usually say "darme **un** gusto". This one makes little sense because you usually are not afraid of good things but it is correct.

1.4 Tengo miedo de que vaya a gustarme mucho este juego. (not "en este juego")

2.1 The most common would be "tengo miedo de dejarme llevar **por** el juego", whoever your sentence is also correct with a different meaning.

2.2 to 2.4 are correct.

2.5 to 2.7 When you say "me temo" usually you have to add "que" so 2.5 should be "me temo que vaya a dejarme llevar por (por)(en) el juego"

3.1 to 3.4 are correct.

As for the definitions:

temer = to fear

temerse = to fear oneself (not very common to be afraid of yourself unless you have a very bad psychological disorder ;) )

tener miedo de = to be afraid of

The translation of the initial sentence in your question **"I'm afraid I will indulge in playing the game."** would be something like **"Me temo que voy a disfrutar de jugar el juego."**. In this sense "me temo" is not exactly about **fear** but about *predicting* that you are going to enjoy the game so much that later will be difficult to let it go, and *that* is what you are kind of afraid of.

Comment: Gracias. Creo que he preguntado poco claro. Quise saber como se dice en español "I am afraid I will spend much in playing the game time more than good. It's not good." Tal vez los oraciones que puse no son correctas ....  y en inglés, "indulge" significa que "[I or T] to ​allow yourself or another ​person to have something ​enjoyable, ​especially more than is good for you:The ​soccer ​fans indulged ​their ​patriotism, ​waving​flags and ​singing ​songs.I ​love ​champagne but I don't often indulge my​self. [T] to give someone anything they ​want and not to ​mind if they ​behave ​badly: "